# Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin (iTunes API)

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, itunes

I'm using iTunes Api to get the 30-seconds preview of a song.

But i get this error:

`[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Dare&limit=1&entity=song&media=music. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

If you go to https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Dare&limit=1&entity=song&media=music you can see that everything goes ok.
Here's my code:

```
function build_player(image)
{
    $.get("https://itunes.apple.com/search", {term: "Dare", limit: 1, entity: "song", media: "music"}, function(result) {
        $(image).parent().append('<audio src="'+result.results[0].previewUrl+'" controls>Il tuo browser non supporta i file audio.</audio>');
    });
}
```

And that function is attached to the onLoad event of an image, like this:

```
    <li>
        <img src="image.jpg" onload="build_player(this);" />
    </li>
```

Comment: Yes you are attempting XSS and itunes.apple.com does not have a CORS header that supports your request. There is nothing you can do in your code to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

An XMLHttpRequest cannot request a resource from a server other than the server the script is being run on. If you look at the [documentation](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html), you can see (just above the large table) that you must place the URL into a `<script>` tag with a `callback` parameter, which is the name of a JS function that will be called when the script tag finishes loading.

Comment: Thank you @The6P4C, but I can't create a <script> tag for every song I want. I'd like to do a dynamic thing, so what should I do to my code? Maybe a document.write('<script src="..."></script>')?